Is there a global equivalent to `testthat::local_reproducible_output()`?
I want to set the width of all my testthat snapshots to 125, the default for .md files on GitHub.
This will make reading tibbles more comfortable.
However, the only way I found was to use testthat::local_reproducible_output(width=125) on every test.
Is there a way to set this option globally in a helper file?

Did you try it and it didn't work?

@MichaelDewar well yes, and if you use it outside test_that(), it doesn't apply. Does it on your computer?
